# How to Manage Multiple Spring Boot in the same project

Tags: spring-boot

Learning Spring Boot as a replacement for some C/C++ daemons.  My goal was to have a single project compiled to a single jar/war.  Then use multiple shell scripts to simply start the one I want via command line.  I'm using Eclipse Kepler to develop and test the individual Spring Boot applications, and noticed an unwanted behavior.  With 4 Spring Boot application classes in the same package, if I start any one of them using an Eclipse launch configuration, all 4 start up in the same Spring Boot.  I suspect because all of them have the @SpringBootApplication annotation, and starting one causes Spring Boot to "scan" the current package and sub-packages.

My question, is there a way to have multiple Spring Boot applications in the same package?  Do I just create a ControllerApplication with a single @SpringBootApplication and pass in the daemon name I want to start and go from there?  Or some other options?  Or do I need to create a separate project for each daemon?  tia, adym

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could annotate your Spring Boot Application with `@ComponentScan's excludeFilters`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.package", 
               excludeFilters = @Filter(SpringBootApplication.class))
```

You may have many dependency issues from this point on, you can resolve them using the same principle.

#### However

This may work inside your IDE, but the generated spring boot jar will only have a single main class attribute.
Because of this, even if you find workarounds, I believe you should either :

- package each spring boot application in its own maven project;
- OR have a single Spring Boot application with multiple Spring profiles.

Take a look at these other answers to launch your spring boot application with multiple spring profiles:

- [spring boot - launch a server and a client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206323/641627)
- [spring boot - launch twice with different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496586/641627)

Comment: Thx Alex!  I think in the interest of simplicity I'm just going to use separate projects per Spring Boot Application.